# Having trouble passing my arraylist into my string parameter

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having a lot trouble trying to pass my list and using the `.get(index)` method. It keeps saying "incompatible data type" but I don't know how to make an array list get strings. Can you help? Here's my method:

```
//a mutator method to store the password list
public void setPasswordList(String newPasswordList) 
{
    ArrayList<String> pL = new ArrayList<String>(); //intalize array list store it into a list
    while(true)
    {
        pL.add(getUserPassword());

        passwordList = newPasswordList;
    }
```

Getter method:

```
public String getPasswordList(){
    return passwordList;
}
```

Comment: where exactly are u facing the issue ?

Comment: I don't understand the question you're asking. In particular, the code doesn't seem complete. Can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) along with a more detailed description of the problem you're having?

Comment: @user2420862 Can you post the code of `getUserPassword()` and the declaration of `passwordList` ? also on witch line does it say `incompatible data type` ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your code declares and populates an ArrayList pL but doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The line `pL.add(getUserPassword());` will throw an error if the signature of your `getUserPassword()` function does not specify  `String` as its return type, or a type castable to `String`.

So, you probabaly want to transform your ArrayList `pL` into a string by concatenating its elements, or maybe you could even discard the array list variable since anyway you want a string to be returned.

For example:

```
public void setPasswordList(String newPasswordList) {
    while(true) {
        passwordList = passwordList + ", " + getUserPassword();
        // Hope there is some code to escape from this loop :)

    }
}
```